# Applying the top hat filter to the inside of the edge of a region

Tags: matlab, filter

I'm looking forward to applying the [top hat filtering](http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/images/ref/imtophat.html) to some region using MATLAB. The region will have borders. If we imagine the borders, there is an inside to the border, and an outside.

So, when I want to apply the filter, how can I determine that I want to do that to the inside of the border for instance?

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is unclear? Do you mean you want to restrict the tophat operation to the inside of a region without affecting the border? Do you mean how do you apply a mask?

Comment: @Try Hard. Thanks for your reply. Imagine two small circles moving along the border. One is moving at the border from the outside, and one from the inside. Say that each circle represents the filter. I want the circle moving along the border from the inside only to move and not the outside. Does that make sense?

Comment: It's not quite clear... `imtophat` is essentially `imopen` plus subtraction of the open from the original image. `imopen` padds the edges of an image with pixels according to rules prior to erosion or dilation. You have to decide what are to apply the operation to and you do that with a mask.

Comment: @Try Hard. Yes, I want to apply the filter to a specific region, where I will be using `imfreehand` for that